# Is it must to include ANOVA results in specified format

Tags: anova

My thesis has calculations that use one-way ANOVA.  There are 40 dependent variables which are needed to be compared under 14 independent variables and each variable has at least 3 groups.  As you can see comparing all the DVs under different IVs would need lots of comparisons and for writing ANOVA results a particular format has to be followed e.g , $F(1, 54) = 4.2, p = 0.04$. So my question is do I have to follow this specific style or can I somehow skip this format in order to avoid painstaking work of writing loads of ANOVA comparisons in text. Plus how to report ANOVA tables and post hoc tables.  The post hoc test would require lots of comparisons within the groups and that would generate lots of tables. How to deal with these situations.  Your input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This depends on the rules for your university. If they say you have to do it you have to do it. I cannot see any real value in repeating from the tables in the text but I am a human not a university.